# Integrating Indicator Function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I tried to integrate a function with an indicator in a journal article (Backtesting Expected Shortfall: Accounting for Tail Risk, 2015, page 7) defined as follows

$Z_t(\alpha) = \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_{0}^{\alpha} h_t(u)du = \frac{1}{\alpha} \int_{0}^{\alpha} 1(u_t\leq u) du= \frac{1}{\alpha}(\alpha - u_t)1(u_t\leq\alpha)$

The answer is already known, only values that satisfy $\alpha - u_t \geq 0$ are allowed.

I just don't know how to get this answer. Basically, I thought the indicator function equals one when $u_t \leq u$, so we could get $\frac{1}{\alpha} \int_{0}^{\alpha} 1~du$. But then the answer should be $1$ and that is not correct.

My question is, how can I get the answer which equals $\frac{1}{\alpha}(\alpha - u_t)1(u_t\leq\alpha)$?

I don't know whether it matters for the answer but $u$, $u_t$ and $\alpha$ are all in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Please supply the title, author, year, and journal of the journal article.

Comment: Since you are new here I am suggesting that there may be another stack with as much claim to your question as this one. http://quant.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

If we only allow $u_t \le \alpha$. $$\mathbb{1}_{u_t\le \alpha}(\alpha)\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_0^\alpha \mathbb{1}_{u_t\le u}du = \mathbb{1}_{u_t\le \alpha}(\alpha)\frac{1}{\alpha}\int_{u_t}^\alpha du = \frac{1}{\alpha}\mathbb{1}_{u_t\le \alpha}(\alpha)(\alpha-u_t)$$

Note that $\mathbb{1}_{u_t\le \alpha}(\alpha)$ represents an indicator that is a function of $\alpha$

Comment: What is 1 sub u(t)?

Comment: I updated the post. It's a function of $\alpha$ that's equal to 1 when $u_t \le \alpha$.